# Using berkeley hardfloat

Tags: scala, riscv, chisel, register-transfer-level

I am using Chisel3 in my project. I tried to import hard float library as folow:

```
import chisel3._ 
import hardfloat._
```

but unfortunately, I am getting:

```
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: edu.berkeley.cs#hardfloat_2.11;1.2: not found
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]
```

I went through couple of repositories that used hardfloat and found out that I was missing this line in my build.sbt:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq("edu.berkeley.cs" %% "hardfloat" % "1.2")
```

but unfortunately I am still getting the error. I then tried to compile projects that use hardfloat without any modification (for example [soundkit](https://github.com/zhemao/soundkit)) but I still get the same error. I used both terminal and InteliJ to compile my project and got the same result. For some reason, the hardfloat library is not even shows up in the External Libraries in IntelliJ .

[image]

I would really appreciate it if someone let me know what might be the issue.

Comment: I don't think this library is published anywhere. https://github.com/ucb-bar/berkeley-hardfloat. You will need clone, build and publish locally.

Comment: @maskarih I suggested an edit to remove the [rtl] tag by mistake, please ignore it. Sorry for any inconvenience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pedrofurla was right. After talking to folks at RISC-V, I got to know that, as you said, the hardfloat is not published to somewhere that sbt can download it. In order to use the library, one has to build and publish it locally:

```
git clone https://github.com/ucb-bar/berkeley-hardfloat.git hardfloat    
cd hardfloat    
sbt publish-local
```

Note: the library works with chisel2